# Как работает продление срока службы батареи ноутбука?

Tags: железо

Кто может по-простому объяснить, как работает функция в ПО производителя ноутбука, ограничивающая уровень заряда батареи до определенного лимита, скажем, до 80-90%.

Прошу сильно не пинать, не спец. по технологиям батарей, но, по-моему, это делается только для того, чтобы избежать перегрева при 100%-м заряде, когда ноутбук сильно загружен и при этом не отсоединён от сети питания. То есть логика в том, чтобы эксплуатировать батарею в приемлемых температурных условиях, потому что, когда заряд доходит до 90-100%, сам аккумулятор начинает нагреваться и повышать температуру в корпусе вдобавок к другим элементам отдающим тепло (процессор, видеокарта...). Конечно, всё имхо и речь только про литий-ионные.

В общем, на мой взгляд, если ноут (или любое другое устройство на Li-ion) не страдает от перегревов, то эту фирменную функцию можно не включать и не лишать себя 15-20% автономности.

Comment: _когда заряд доходит до 90-100%, сам аккумулятор начинает нагреваться_ - у нормальных производителей не начинает, а совсем наоборот. Чем выше уровень заряда, тем ниже зарядный ток дает контроллер. Так что даже остывает.

Comment: При полном заряде аккумулятор не греется, если система не загружена, то есть не выполняется какая-то сложная работа. Попробуйте зарядить батарею до 100% и не отсоединяя питание запустить требовательную к ресурсам задачу, аккумулятор начнёт нагреваться, и чем выше нагрузка, тем выше температура батареи.